# Underline in metauml

Tags: metapost, metauml

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Class.A("A")
       ("-instance: A")
       ("-A()",
        "+instance(): A");

drawObjects(A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{Class \texttt{A} as a singleton}
\label{fig:uml-a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I make `+instance(): A` underlined to mark it as a static method?

Is it possible to disable converting `+` and `-` to graphics ?

Egreg's solution below works but is there any way to draw "true" underline? For example if I add something below underlined part I would have to move line maually. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `mpsettings={input metauml;}`; then you can use Metapost for drawing a line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Class.A("A")
       ("-instance: A")
       ("-A()",
        "+instance(): A");

drawObjects(A);

draw A.sw+(13,1.5) -- A.se+(-4,1.5);

\end{mpost}
\caption{Class \texttt{A} as a singleton}
\label{fig:uml-a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to change the `+` and `-` to something else than the default, one should study in detail the source `metauml.mp`

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip. But this is not an answer to my question.

Comment: OK, this works. It is not an underlined text but looks good :)

Comment: Is it possible to add "true" underline?

Answer (score 3):

Idea in drawing line under "attribute" label. (reputation killed image)

```
+---------------------+
|      Singleton      |
+---------------------+
| -  static Instance  |
|   ----------------- |
+---------------------+
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

This is variation on  egreg 's  answer. It is possible that more accurate answer exist...

```
input metauml;

beginfig(1);
    Class.SingletonLite("Singleton")("- static Instance")();

    drawObject(SingletonLite);

    draw SingletonLite.attributeStack.pict[0].sw -- SingletonLite.attributeStack.pict[0].se ;
endfig;

end.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You now have the rep required for posting images so you could revise your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following suggestions work with the code in the [master branch of MetaUML](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML/tree/master), but not with MetaUML 0.2.5.

It is possible to explicitly mark class features as abstract or static:

[metaUML class diagram: set some methods as abstract in an abstract class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186020/metauml-class-diagram-set-some-methods-as-abstract-in-an-abstract-class)

Text can be underlined as follows:

```
Picture.a("foo");
a.info.textDecoration := "underline";
```

The use of locks as visibility markers has been discontinued in favour of the standard UML notation.