# metaUML class diagram: set some methods as abstract in an abstract class

Tags: italic, abstract, metauml

I usually found the answer of my questions in StackExchange or over Internet. But this time I can't. I look for a lot yesterday and I didn't find a solution.

Recently I started to use LaTex, and I'm using metaUML for describe a few of my important classes. But I have a problem with abstract classes.

I have an abstract class with some methods abstract, an the rest of the methods not. I want to put the abstract methods in Italic or Oblique (value metauml_defaultFontOblique), but I don't know how to access to the font of each method to put that value.

For example:

```
input metauml;
beginfig(1);

AbstractClass.AbsClass("AbsClass")()(
"+AbsClass()",
"+abstractMethod(): void",
"+nonAbstractMethod(): void"
);

drawObject(AbsClass);
endfig;
end
```

[image: The result of the above code]

Here I want abstractMethod will appear in italic, and noAbstractMethod will appear normal.

How can I do this?

I can put the name of the class in Italic if I add:

```
AbsClass.info.iName.iFont.name := metauml_defaultFontOblique;
```

And I can put all the methods in Italic if I use:

```
AbsClass.info.iMethodStack.iPict.iFont.name := metauml_defaultFontOblique;
```

[image: The result if I put all methods in italic using the above code]

But I only want the abstract method in Italic.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are at least two packages based on PGF for building UML diagrams: `pgf-umlcd` and `pgf-umlsd`. The Metapost based `metauml` has severe limitations about fonts, which shouldn't be a concern with the other packages.

Comment: Despite of it looks like I can set the methods in italic (because I can set all the methods in italic), i will try to use pgf-umlcd as you recomended. Thanks for your fast answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was not possible in MetaUML 0.2.5 due to the way in which method stacks were generated.

The [master branch of MetaUML](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML/tree/master) now allows for abstract, static classic features:

```
Class.A("A")
    (static "-instanceCount:int")
    (static "+getInstanceCount():int", abstract "+work()");
```

[image: MetaUML: Static and abstract class features]

Comment: Nice to know, and welcome to the site :) Be sure to update this answer once that feature is added. :)