# How to define a method as abstract in umlclass of package TikZ-UML

Tags: tikz-uml

I read the TikZ-UML documentation thouroughly and googled a lot, but the only similar response I found was [set abstract methods in abstract class with metaUML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186020/metauml-class-diagram-set-some-methods-as-abstract-in-an-abstract-class) but it uses metaUML and not TikZ-UML.

In UML abstract methods are supposed to be rendered as italic, so I would like to accomplish something like:
[image: umlclass]

The only way I found to do that is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \umlclass[type=abstract]{AbstractClass}{
  }{
    +\textit{abstractMethod()}\\
    +concreteMethod()
  }
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I do not like it because it mixes presentation with semantic, is there a native, semantic way of doing it?

Comment: You could do `\let\abstractM\textit` and then `+\abstractM{abstractMethod()}`, would that be semantic enough? That is a sort of serious suggestion, if you have both types of methods then you will need to indicate one way or another which methods are abstract and which are concrete, and the implementation of that would be nothing more than changing to italics or not.

Comment: It sure is cleaner and more readable than my solution, but I still don't like it. May be it's me, but if what you say were true, shouldn't it be the same for abstract class? Or static method? You can \textit or \underline them , but instead there are type=abstract or \umlstatic for those, why not \umlabstract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package manual describes the two commands `\umlstatic` and `\umlvirt` for static and virtual (abstract) classes, respectively. See [https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/html/web-tikz-uml-userguidech2.html#x4-90002.1.2](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/html/web-tikz-uml-userguidech2.html#x4-90002.1.2):

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlclass{namespace::A}{ 
  + n : uint \\ \umlstatic{-- i : int} \\ \# r : const float 
  }{ 
  + setA(i : int) : void \\ \umlvirt{\# getA() : A} 
} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Note that in the source code of the package these two commands are defined as simple wrappers around `\underline` and `\textit` (similar to my comment above of aliasing a command to `\textit`). See line 622-623 of `tikz-uml.sty`:

```
\newcommand{\umlstatic}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
\newcommand{\umlvirt}[1]{\textit{#1}}%
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw virtual but I missed it stood for abstract, my bad. I know it may seem nitpicking, but I'm a teacher and I need to enforce between "concept" and "realisation" or "semantic" and "representation".